# Why is my Javascript output for my Mad Lib blank? Possibly innerhtml issue

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I'm sure this is a simple fix but I don't see the problem. I was following a tutorial on making a JS Mad Lib and I wanted to experiment with the output. Adding more inputs. Well, when I put in all the inputs. It comes up blank. please keep in mind this is a project in progress and not the finished project. Any help is appreciated

```js
    const userprompts = document.querySelector("#prompts");
    const story = document.querySelector("#story");
    const error = document.querySelector("#error");

    const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click", completestory, false);

    const reset= document.querySelector("#reset");
    reset.addEventListener("click", resetPage, false);

    document.querySelector('#name').focus();

    const thename = document.querySelector("#name");
    const firstverb = document.querySelector("#firstverb");
    const firstnoun = document.querySelector("#firstnoun");
    const adjective = document.querySelector("#adjective");
    const secondnoun = document.querySelector("#secondnoun");
    const adverb = document.querySelector("#adverb");
    const storyOutput = document.querySelector("#storyOutput")

    window.addEventListener("keydown", keydownHandler, false);

    function keydownHandler(event) {
      console.log("Enter key pressed");

    }

    function checkStory() {

    }

    function completestory() {
      let finishedstory = "";
      finishedstory += "There once was a person named " + thename.value + ". ";
      finishedstory += "One day, " + thename.value + "was " + firstverb.value + "out in the "
      + firstnoun.value + ". ";
      finishedstory += "All of a sudden, " + thename.value + "saw a " + adjective.value +
      "dragon!" ;
      finishedstory += thename.value + "thought for a second and did the only thing they could think of "
      + "They grabbed a " + secondnoun.value + ". " ;
      finishedstory += "With the " + secondnoun.value + "in hand. " + thename.value + adverb.value + "attacked the dragon.";
      finishedstory += "The dragon became very confused and left. The End";

      storyOutput.innerHTML = finishedstory();
    }

    function resetPage() {

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mod3Layout.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sean's Mad Lib</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Sean's Wacky Mad Lib</h1><hr>

    <div id="prompts">
      <h3>Please enter your prompts here</h3>
      <p>Enter a name here:
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
        </p>
        <p>Enter a verb here:
          <input id="firstverb" type="text" placeholder="verb 1">
          </p>
          <p>Enter a noun here:
            <input id="firstnoun" type="text" placeholder="noun 1">
            </p>
            <p>Enter an adjective here:
              <input id="adjective" type="text" placeholder="adjective">
             </p>
             <p>Enter another noun here:
               <input id="secondnoun" type="text" placeholder="noun 2">
             </p>
             <p>Finally, Enter an adverb here:
               <input id="adverb" type="text" placeholder="adverb">
             </p>
             <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
             <p id="error">You did not answer all the questions. Please try
               again</p>
      </div>
      <div id="story">
        <p>Let's see what you wrote.</p>
        <p id="storyOutput">Hello Dave</p>
        <button id="reset" type="button" name="Reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: You're currently getting an error because `finishedstory` is not a function, but you're calling it; e.g., `finishedstory()`. It's actually just a `String` so try `storyOutput.innerHTML = finishedstory;` in your `completestory` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I knew it would be something simple

Answer (score 0):

You were receiving the error `Uncaught TypeError: finishedstory is not a function` because of this line in your `completestory` function:

`storyOutput.innerHTML = finishedstory();`

As you defined it, `finishedstory` is a `String`; just change that line to `storyOutput.innerHTML = finishedstory;` and the error no longer gets triggered.

```js
    const userprompts = document.querySelector("#prompts");
    const story = document.querySelector("#story");
    const error = document.querySelector("#error");

    const submit = document.querySelector("#submit");
    submit.addEventListener("click", completestory, false);

    const reset= document.querySelector("#reset");
    reset.addEventListener("click", resetPage, false);

    document.querySelector('#name').focus();

    const thename = document.querySelector("#name");
    const firstverb = document.querySelector("#firstverb");
    const firstnoun = document.querySelector("#firstnoun");
    const adjective = document.querySelector("#adjective");
    const secondnoun = document.querySelector("#secondnoun");
    const adverb = document.querySelector("#adverb");
    const storyOutput = document.querySelector("#storyOutput")

    function checkStory() {

    }

    function completestory() {
      let finishedstory = "";
      finishedstory += "There once was a person named " + thename.value + ". ";
      finishedstory += "One day, " + thename.value + "was " + firstverb.value + "out in the "
      + firstnoun.value + ". ";
      finishedstory += "All of a sudden, " + thename.value + "saw a " + adjective.value +
      "dragon!" ;
      finishedstory += thename.value + "thought for a second and did the only thing they could think of "
      + "They grabbed a " + secondnoun.value + ". " ;
      finishedstory += "With the " + secondnoun.value + "in hand. " + thename.value + adverb.value + "attacked the dragon.";
      finishedstory += "The dragon became very confused and left. The End";

      storyOutput.innerHTML = finishedstory;
    }

    function resetPage() {

    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Mod3Layout.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sean's Mad Lib</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Sean's Wacky Mad Lib</h1><hr>

    <div id="prompts">
      <h3>Please enter your prompts here</h3>
      <p>Enter a name here:
        <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="name">
        </p>
        <p>Enter a verb here:
          <input id="firstverb" type="text" placeholder="verb 1">
          </p>
          <p>Enter a noun here:
            <input id="firstnoun" type="text" placeholder="noun 1">
            </p>
            <p>Enter an adjective here:
              <input id="adjective" type="text" placeholder="adjective">
             </p>
             <p>Enter another noun here:
               <input id="secondnoun" type="text" placeholder="noun 2">
             </p>
             <p>Finally, Enter an adverb here:
               <input id="adverb" type="text" placeholder="adverb">
             </p>
             <button id="submit" type="button">Submit</button>
             <p id="error">You did not answer all the questions. Please try
               again</p>
      </div>
      <div id="story">
        <p>Let's see what you wrote.</p>
        <p id="storyOutput">Hello Dave</p>
        <button id="reset" type="button" name="Reset">Reset</button>
        </div>
```